# Strength of Dictionary in Tesseract 3

Tags: ocr, tesseract

How do I increase/decrease the strength of the dictionary in tesseract 3 ?

In the FAQ it says I need to change the value of "NON_WERD" and
"GARBAGE_STRING" but they do not exist in Tesseract 3.

Comment: Have you had any success? I have twiddled the values for non_dict_word and non_freq_dict_word and not seen any change in results....

Comment: @KaolinFire I had the same problem but finally found the reason - [you need to set enable_new_segsearch](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29843379/492336).

Comment: I'll have to try that—it's been a very long time since I was playing with it, don't *quite* remember why we were... :) Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

According to 
http://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/wiki/FAQ, you change these variables:

```
enable_new_segsearch    1
language_model_penalty_non_freq_dict_word 0.2
language_model_penalty_non_dict_word 0.3
```

Increase their values to make Tesseract more biased to dictionary words.

**Note:** You must set `enable_new_segsearch`, otherwise [they'll have no effect](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29843379/492336).

Comment: The project and Wiki have moved to [GitHub](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/wiki/ControlParams).

Comment: Does this also apply to 4.x?

Answer (score 1):

To turn tesseract's language-knowing abilities entirely, run each of these:

```
tess.setTessVariable("load_system_dawg", "false");
tess.setTessVariable("load_freq_dawg", "false");
tess.setTessVariable("load_punc_dawg", "false");
tess.setTessVariable("load_number_dawg", "false");
tess.setTessVariable("load_unambig_dawg", "false");
tess.setTessVariable("load_bigram_dawg", "false");
tess.setTessVariable("load_fixed_length_dawgs", "false");
```

Or, for finer control, just some of them. (I don't know of a place explaining well what they all do, but the names are pretty explanatory) This is code from my current project, using Tess4J, but you can easily translate them to c++ or a config file or whatever else you need.