# "language_model_penalty_non_dict_word" has no effect in tesseract 3.01

Tags: command-line, ocr, tesseract

I'm setting `language_model_penalty_non_dict_word` through a config file for Tesseract 3.01, but its value doesn't have any effect. I've tried with multiple images, and multiple values for it, but the output for each image is always the same. Another user has noticed the same [in a comment in another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8940795/strength-of-dictionary-in-tesseract-3#comment19036313_8940795).

**Edit:** After looking inside the source, the variable `language_model_penalty_non_dict_word` is used only inside the function `float LanguageModel::ComputeAdjustedPathCost`.

However, this function is never called! It is referenced only by 2 functions - `LanguageModel::UpdateBestChoice()` and `LanguageModel::AddViterbiStateEntry()`. I placed breakpoints in those functions, but they weren't being called, as well.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After some debugging, I finally found out the reason - the function `Wordrec::SegSearch()` wasn't being called (and it is up there in the call graph of `LanguageModel::ComputeAdjustedPathCost()`).

From this code:

```
  if (enable_new_segsearch) {
    SegSearch(&chunks_record, word->best_choice,
              best_char_choices, word->raw_choice, state);
  } else {
    best_first_search(&chunks_record, best_char_choices, word,
                      state, fixpt, best_state);
  }
```

So you need to set `enable_new_segsearch` in the config file:

```
enable_new_segsearch    1

language_model_penalty_non_freq_dict_word 0.2
language_model_penalty_non_dict_word 0.3
```

Comment: Does this also apply to 4.x?